# Need a Quick Way to Disable All Windows Server Security

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have several test machines on which annoying (in)security prompts block my research and development work.

I am not at all concerned with the security of these machines and have no problem with them catching fire during my research. The more they crash and burn, the better!

I am looking for a script (or other turn-key means) for shutting down all security at once.

This should be possible with PowerShell, DSC, and/or Group Policy scripting.

Comment: Most operating systems are complex. Like the cockpit of a 747. There's no "one button" in the cockpit of a 747 that's labelled "Fly from L.A. to Sydney."

Comment: `I am looking for a script (or other turn-key means) for shutting down all security at once` - The security of a system isn't dependent upon just a single component, it's dependent upon many components. You have UAC, IE ESC, the Windows Firewall, etc., etc.

Comment: @RyanRies - I am aware it is not a single thing; I implemented portions of Group Policy and spent 5 years working inside the Microsoft sweatshop; it really **should** be a single thing, however, especially when I am working with a test machine that is there to do my bidding, and nothing else!

Comment: @joeqwerty - Again, the fact that it is not a single component is the very reason I need a script or program with which to make it so; surely there is a way to achieve it with DSC or PowerShell; I am the Administrator of these machines and should have full power over their state configuration; I am surprised that this is not considered a standard request.

Comment: @RyanRies - To follow your analogy, I would like to avoid being prompted with "Are you sure you want to fly from L.A. to Sydney" every time I make a course correction or cruising altitude change.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really after is disabling UAC (User Account Control). Is that the case?

Comment: @joeqwerty - Disabling UAC is always the first thing I do when I bring a new system online (especially my development workstation); it's the other bits, that pop up incessantly, that I seek to suppress.

Comment: Telling us that it's `the other bits` without telling us specifically what those `bits` are leaves us in the dark. I've already mentioned IE ESC and the Windows Firewall. What other `bits` are you referring to?

Comment: @joeqwerty - you are missing the point; as soon as the way to achieve results becomes a manual laundry list, it is of no use to me. I guess there is a market for an actual automated solution to fill this vacuum, and I will have to create it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, there is no single magic button... But the most 'annoying' security features you can disable are Smart Screen, UAC and IE Enhanced Security Configuration.

Comment: thank you for providing an answer; since the magic button does not exist, there is an opportunity here to create it; I look forward to slaying this windmill with code!